# In VSIX, reading Configuration Properties of CSPROJ throws COMException (method or operation not implemented)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In my VSIX (VS Extension), I am reading the config properties' .Value of each of the projects in the currently loaded solution.  For a C# (csproj) project:

```
var configurationManager = project.ConfigurationManager;
if (configurationManager == null) return null;
var configuration = configurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
if (configuration == null) return null;
var properties = configuration.Properties;
if (properties == null) return null;

foreach (var property in properties.Cast<Property>())
{
    // reading property.Name is OK but reading property.Value gives the COMException 'not implemented'
    if (property == null) continue;
    if (property.Name == "StartWorkingDirectory") workingDir = (string)property.Value;
    if (property.Name == "StartAction") startProject = 0 == (int)property.Value;
    if (property.Name == "StartProgram") startExtProg = (string)property.Value;
    if (property.Name == "StartURL") startBrowser = (string)property.Value;
    // etc...
}
```

For every property, I get the COMException: 'The method or operation is not implemented' when I try to read the .Value property, though .Name is fine.  All the searched for properties seem to exist, their .Value just can't be read.

This is a brand new VSIX project created with the VS2022 template that includes Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK and the Microsoft.VisualStudio.BuildTools in the references.

That seems to include every DTE* reference, stdole, and the other VS COM dlls like VSLangProj* (If I try to add these as project references, it says they're already included in the build process).  So, I tried adding all those references via nuget packages, but it had no effect I could see and the error remains.

So I can't find anything on how to read these properties on my C# projects (csproj).  They're simple C# 8 Console applications, empty that I just created.

Here are all my VSIX project's references, including the ones pulled in by nuget but probably don't need to be:

```
envdte
envdte80
envdte90
Microsoft.CSharp
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK
Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools
NJsonSchema
PresentationCore
PresentationFramework
stdole
System
VSLangProj
VSLangProj100
VSLangProj110
VSLangProj140
VSLangProj150
VSLangProj80
VSLangProj90
WindowsBase
WindowsFormsIntegration
```

I'm using VS2022, fully updated as of March 2024.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Source at: https://github.com/cbordeman/switchstartupproject/pull/4

Comment: Is this issue only occurs on new vs version or also in the old version of vs?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I don't know, the extension won't load at all on VS2019.  The described error occurs when debugging against VS2022.

Comment: I've added the link to my fork on Github.

Comment: Is the Property in properties.Cast<Property>() DEFINATELY EnvDTE.Property?  Do you get same behavior if you use OfType<> not Cast<>?

Comment: @tolanj It is definitely EnvDTE.Property.  Using .Name works, .Value throws the exception.